# Is the argument of the $\sin$ function for a monochromatic plane wave dimensionless?

Tags: waves, dimensional-analysis

I was looking at [the following representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinusoidal_plane_wave) of a monochromatic plane wave:
$$
F(\vec x, t) = A\sin(2\pi\nu(\vec x \cdot \hat n - ct) + \phi)
$$
but, upon analyzing the argument of the sin function, it doesn't appear to be dimensionless. As shown below:
$$
\begin{align}
[2\pi\nu(\vec x \cdot \hat n - ct) + \phi] &= [T]^{-1}([L] - [L][T]^{-1}[T])\\
&= [T]^{-1}([L] - [L])\\
&= [T]^{-1}([L])\\
&= [L][T]^{-1}
\end{align}
$$
as one can see, the argument is in units of $[L][T]^{-1}$. Is there something that I'm missing? The argument to a trigonometric function must be dimensionless.

Comment: $\nu$ is *not* the frequency in hertz. The Wiki article says that it is the *spatial frequency* so $\nu x$ is dimensionless.

Answer (score 4):

There is something you're missing. You're missing that in this formula, $\nu$ is the spatial frequency (or wavenumber), not the temporal frequency. It has units of $\rm{length}^{-1}$.

Comment: Ah, of course. I'm used to $\nu$ being used for temporal frequency.